# Where to install multiple compiler-specific libraries on UNIX-like systems

Tags: linux, cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I need to install the same C++/Fortran library compiled with different compilers on the system with CMake. Is there a standard  location where to install the different compiler-specific versions of the same library on the system? For example, assuming that `lib.so` and `lib.a` have already been installed using the system package manager under `/usr/`, is it good practice to install each of the additional compiler-specific versions in a different folder under let's say `usr/local`. Or is there a better way of doing this that you can advise?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many compilers/libraries/versions you have. If you have just a few of them, I think that (almost) any choice on the location is right but I personally prefer /opt/ paths for manually installed code. But if you start having several combinations of them you easily get in trouble. Besides, I think that the question on the "best" location is related to the question on the "best" way to switch from the usage of one library to another one, possibly avoiding to manually set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, libraies to link or similar things.

I give some personal recommendations according to my experience for systems where you want to support many libraries/applications with many compilers/versions and also provide them for many users:

1. Do not use root user to install compiled software: just use an "installer account" and give read and execute permissions when needed to other users
2. Select a path for compiled software, e.g. /opt and define two subfolders /opt/build and /opt/install, the first one for your sources and where you compile them, the second as compilation target
3. Create some subfolders based on categories, e.g. /compilers, /libraries, /applications, ... from both /opt/build and /opt/install
4. Start preparing compilers under /compilers, e.g. /compilers/gnu/6.3 or /compilers/intel/2017. When possible compile them, e.g. from /opt/build/compilers/gnu/6.3 to /opt/install/compilers/gnu/6.3 or just put them into /install folder, e.g. /opt/install/compilers/intel/2017
5. Prepare the tree for libraries (or applications) adding subfolders which specify the version, the compiler and compiler version, e.g. compile from /opt/build/libraries/boost/1.64.0/gnu/6.3 and install to /opt/install/libraries/boost/1.64.0/gnu/6.3

At this stage, you have well organized things. But:

- It is difficult to decide which library you want to use, you have to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH or manually link the right one and the situation is worse when you deal also with applications
- You are not considering dependencies between libraries: how can I force using g++ 6.3 when linking against boost/1.64.0/gnu/6.3?

To address these and many other issues, a good way of doing is using a tool which can help you, e.g. http://modules.sourceforge.net/ so that you can easily switch to one library to another one, force dependency, get help, and in general have something less error prone in the daily usage.